# is microsoft blocking chrome and firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

The following links do not work on Firefox nor Chrome
only on Internet Explorer

- http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/60297607-5fd4-4da4-97e1-3715e90c1a23
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287992%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

does anyone know how to circumvent this?

Comment: Both sites working in Firefox 13.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55c24bf1-2636-4f94-831d-28db8505ce00?SRC=VSIDE

Updated Firefox to 13.01, still this page doesnt load there (load with chrome)

Comment: I recommend using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to diagnose what is causing this issue.  Look at the web traffic and see if the page is being sent back after the request.